# Failed to resolve: net.butterflytv.utils:rtmp-client:3.1.0

Tags: android-studio

I am having this problem when synchronizing the project in Android Studio Bumblebee.

Resolution failed: net.butterflytv.utils:rtmp-client:3.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: liveVideoBroadcasterSDK

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /*
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })*/
    implementation 'net.butterflytv.utils:rtmp-client:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding: jcenter()

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter() //----here
    }
}

include ':app'
include ':liveVideoBroadcasterSDK'
```